# Correct vertical spacing

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment

I have this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{#1\par\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\test{\begin{align*}\text{Equation}\end{align*}}

\vspace{25pt}

\test{\centerline{Not equation}}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it'll look like this:

[image]

Now, the vertical distance between 'Equation' and it's separator line is greater than the distance between 'Not equation' and it's line. I want it to be the same as in the 'Not equation' case. How do I do it please?

Comment: That's because a vertical space is added after displayed equations, controlled by `\belowdisplayskip`. Maybe a definition like `\newcommand{\test}[1]{{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}#1\par\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}` instead might work?

Comment: Just add the tag \belowdisplayskip=0pt in your \test definition...

Comment: `\centerline` is a polain tex command that should not really be used in latex documents, it does not use the same conventions as latex constructs such as the `center` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a surprise: a display environment will leave some vertical space above and below it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{#1}\par
  \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\test{$\begin{aligned}[b]\text{Equation}&=\text{aaa}\\&=\text{bbb}\end{aligned}$}

\bigskip\bigskip

\test{Not equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\centerline`.

Answer (score 1):

Many LaTeX environments add space above and/or below them. In the case of math equations, it is the `\belowdisplayskip` which adds some `vspace` below your `align*`. To undo this `vspace` for most environments and not only for math ones, we may add `\vspace{-\lastskip}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{#1\par\vspace{-\lastskip}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\test{\begin{align*}\text{Equation}\end{align*}}

\vspace{25pt}

\test{Not equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]